# Linq to XML with VB.NET

Tags: xml, wpf, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to get to grips with Linq to XML - coming from MSXML. I would like to loop all elements contained within 'Root' in the following XML, returning the element name, and values for each of the attributes.

XML:

```
<Root>
    <April Target="55" Forecast="30" Result="30"/>
    <May Target="98" Forecast="67" Result="84"/>
    <June Target="133" Forecast="109" Result="119"/>
    <July Target="183" Forecast="146" Result="150"/>
    <August Target="239" Forecast="182" Result="188"/>
    <September Target="278" Forecast="211" Result="217"/>
    <October Target="320" Forecast="251" Result="489"/>
    <November Target="372" Forecast="281" Result="489"/>
    <December Target="386" Forecast="324" Result="489"/>
    <January Target="420" Forecast="352" Result="489"/>
    <February Target="464" Forecast="384" Result="489"/>
    <March Target="524" Forecast="445" Result="489"/>
</Root>
```

For example, for each iteration of the loop, I would like to be able to populate the following variables:

```
MonthName = Taken from the element name
Target = Taken from the attribute value
Forecast = Taken from the attribute value
Result = Taken from the attribute value
```

I have managed to load the document as follows:

```
Dim xDoc As New XDocument
        xDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\Users\Major\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Dashboard\XML\YTD - Copy.xml")
```

But all code I can find relates to getting elements with specific names, where I want to loop all children of Root

Comment: Just use `xDoc.Elements("Root").Elements()`, no need to specify a name if you don't need a specific one. Not posting as answer because I don't know VB.NET enough to write any good sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the answers. The route I've found easiest is as follows:

```
xDoc = XDocument.Load("XML Path Here")
Dim MonthNodes As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xDoc.Element("Root").Descendants

        For Each MonthNode As XElement In MonthNodes
            Debug.Print(MonthNode.Attribute("Target").Value)
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim xDoc = <Root>
               <April Target="55" Forecast="30" Result="30"/>
               <May Target="98" Forecast="67" Result="84"/>
               <June Target="133" Forecast="109" Result="119"/>
               <July Target="183" Forecast="146" Result="150"/>
               <August Target="239" Forecast="182" Result="188"/>
               <September Target="278" Forecast="211" Result="217"/>
               <October Target="320" Forecast="251" Result="489"/>
               <November Target="372" Forecast="281" Result="489"/>
               <December Target="386" Forecast="324" Result="489"/>
               <January Target="420" Forecast="352" Result="489"/>
               <February Target="464" Forecast="384" Result="489"/>
               <March Target="524" Forecast="445" Result="489"/>
           </Root>

For Each node In xDoc.Elements()
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name)

    For Each attr In node.Attributes
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", attr.Name, attr.Value)
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:-

```
Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Your_Data.xml")
Dim result = (From d In xdoc.Root.Elements()
                   Select New With {.MonthName = d.Name.LocalName,
                                    .Target = d.Attribute("Target").Value,
                                    .Forecast = d.Attribute("Forecast").Value,
                                    .Result = d.Attribute("Result").Value}).ToList()
```

Then you can simply use the `For Each` loop to iterate through the result:-

```
For Each output In result
   Console.WriteLine("Month: {0},Target: {1}, Forecast: {2}, Result: {3}", output.MonthName, output.Target, output.Forecast, output.Result)
Next
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. How do I then get the data out of the list?

Comment: @JiminyCricket - You can simply use a loop, Please check my update.